# Continuous Jquery rotation transfer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, transformation, repeat

I have two buttons which are located on opposite sides of a form ("Next" on front, "Submit" on back). The buttons perform the rotation (180deg) correctly, however, they only work for one click each. In other words, the onClick command only works once per click. Is there any way for me to reset my transformation in order repeat my rotation on click infinitely?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='next']").on("click", function() {
      // console.log( "The NEXT Button Worked!" );
      $(".form").css("transform", "rotateY(180deg)");
    })
    $("input[name='back']").on("click", function() {
      // console.log( "The BACK Button Worked!" );
      $(".formFlipAgain").css("transform", "rotateY(180deg)");
    })
  });



  function showBack() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("backSide").style.display = "block";
    }, 600);
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("frontSide").style.display = "none";
    }, 600);
  };

  function showFront() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("frontSide").style.display = "block";
    }, 600);
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("backSide").style.display = "none";
    }, 600);
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Introduce two flags.

```
var flag1=0;
var flag2=0
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name='next']").on("click", function() {
    // console.log( "The NEXT Button Worked!" );
    $(".form").css("transform", "rotateY("+flag1?0:180+"deg)");
    flag1=!flag1;
  })
  $("input[name='back']").on("click", function() {
    // console.log( "The BACK Button Worked!" );
    $(".formFlipAgain").css("transform", "rotateY("+flag2?0:180+"deg)");
    flag2=!flag2;
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks nicael, but the problem is still there. The button already works an infinite amount of time, but the "vertical flip rotation" only works once per click (with the original code that is... entering the flags disabled those too). No clue what I can do to keep repeating the transformations.

Comment: @KGhumaan Oh sorry, I had a typo! See the edited answer.

Comment: @KGhumaan Do you still have the problem using my code?

Comment: sadly yess... still having trouble.. I think i wasn't clear enough when stating my problem. The rotation happens every time I click the buttons, the problem is that I can not get the "Transition-duration: 2s" to work after I click each button once. In other words, after I return to the front and click the "next" button again, the vertical flipping animation happens too quick. The CSS property for "transition-duration" doesn't continuously work when I hit a button more than once. Hope I was clear enough. The buttons work properly, the "vertical flip animation" doesn't continuously work.